# flot axisLabel not working

Tags: flot

I can't seem to get labels working on my basic Flot graph, I have stripped it down to the basics but I still can't get it to work;

```
<div id="graph" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var d1 = [[0, 13], [1, 13], [2, 13], [3, 0], [4, 17], [5, 17], [6, 13]];

    $.plot($("#graph"), [ 
        {
            data: d1,
            bars: {
                show: true
            },
            xaxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Hops'
            },
            yaxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Traceroute'
            }
       }
    ]);

});
</script>
```

Below is the graph I am getting. As you can see, no errors in the Chrome debug window. I did have the following simple axis label formatting settings included also but it still wouldn't work:

```
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
            axisLabelPadding: 5
```

[image]

Comment: There are a few axis-label plugins out there; which are you using, and what version?

Comment: @DNS Sorry I forgot to mention that, I am using https://github.com/xuanluo/flot-axislabels

Comment: It looks like you already solved the problem, but you may in any case want to try https://github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels. This is Mark Cote's version; it's based on Xuanluo's, but he has cleaned it up and made further improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how I have fixed this, but by making it more complex, I have. Perhaps a bug?

Now it works with this code:

```
<div id="graph" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var d1 = [[0, 13]];
    var d2 = [[1, 13]]; 
    var d3 = [[2, 13]];
    var d4 = [[3, 30]];
    var d5 = [[4, 17]];
    var d6 = [[5, 17]];
    var d7 = [[6, 13]];

    var data1 = [
        {
            data: d1,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fillColor:  "#CAFFD8"
            },
            color: "#CAFFD8"
        },
        {
            data: d2,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fillColor:  "#CAFFD8"
            },
            color: "#CAFFD8"
        },
        {
            data: d3,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fillColor:  "#CAFFD8"
            },
            color: "#CAFFD8"
        },
        {
            data: d4,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fillColor:  "#FF7575"
            },
            color: "#FF7575"
        },
        {
            data: d5,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fillColor:  "#FFFF75"
            },
            color: "#FFFF75"
        },
        {
            data: d6,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fillColor:  "#FFFF75"
            },
            color: "#FFFF75"
        },
        {
            data: d7,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fillColor:  "#CAFFD8"
            },
            color: "#CAFFD8"
        },
    ];

    $.plot($("#graph"), data1, { 
            xaxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Hops',
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                axisLabelPadding: 5
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 30,
                axisLabel: 'Traceroute',
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                axisLabelPadding: 5
            }
       });

});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It's because you were originally putting your graph options inside your data object.  In your second version you have your data series in the first argument and the graph options in the 2nd for your call to `$.plot([data],{options})`.

Comment: @Ryley What a wally I was. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [jquery.flot.axislabels](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RuiPereira/flot/axislabels/jquery.flot.axislabels.js) plugin in your html code.