# Unable to get label with axislabels.js

Tags: jquery, flot

I have been working on FLOT for few days now. The API is awesome and evrything works fine except that even after including jQuery.flot.axislabels.js, I cannot get to display any label name.

I have worked on this a lot and tried almost everything available on this. Below is a code snippet that I have been trying:

```
 $.plot($("#graph"), [
    {
        data: d1,
        bars: {
            show:true,
            align: "center",
            barWidth: 0.5,
            horizontal: true,
            fillColor: "#6199CC",
            lineWidth: 0
        },
        xaxis: {
            axisLabel: "Label for X-axis",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            max: 200,
            tickColor: "#5E5E5E",
            color:"black"
        },
        yaxis: {
            axisLabel: "Label for y-axis",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 3,
            tickColor: "#5E5E5E",
            ticks: ticks, 
            color:"black"
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            borderWidth: 2,
            backgroundColor: { colors: ["#171717", "#4F4F4F"] }
        }
    }
]);
```

I have tried changing xaxis to xaxes and same for y. I have tried `show:true` inside xaxis and yaxis options. But all I get is the numbers on axes and no labels.

Do I really need to specify a div for the same (as I found on some sites, but I don't believe so for now), if yes, how to integrate it with axislabels.js or may be I am missing some properties, like something I need to set to true or show.

The rest of my code is fine, gives no error and renders a beautiful plot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [flot axisLabel not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559204/flot-axislabel-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as duplicate of [flot axisLabel not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559204/flot-axislabel-not-working).

You have your options included in the data part of the plot method call.
Separate them and it works (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/703q73az/)):

```
$.plot($("#graph"), [d1], {
    bars: {
        show: true,
        align: "center",
        ...
    },
    ...        
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ Raidri....and ya really silly on my part. The more silly was that I had already went through the question that you have pointed out but didn't read all the answers/comment.